# How to add size in MB or GB or TB as well as the total of size and files of the files counted/sum in the command described

Tags: shell-script

How to add size in MB or GB or TB as well as the total size and files of the files counted/sum in the command described

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  sort -z |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
    echo -n "$i: "
    echo
    (
      find "$i" -type f |
        sed -n 's/..*\.//p'|
        sort |
        uniq -c
    )
    echo
  done
```

what I have:

```
.:
1 csv
2 docx
3 xlxs

./dir1:
  1csv
./dir2:
 1 docx
 2 xlsx

./dir3/:
 1 docx
 1 xlsx
```

what I need:

```
.:
1MB 1 csv
2MB 2 docx
3GB 3 xlxs
total 3.3 GB and 6 files

./dir1:
1MB  1csv
total 1MB and 1 file

./dir2:
1MB 1 docx
2GB 2 xlsx
total 1.1 GB and 2 files

./dir3/:
1MB 1 docx
3GB 1 xlsx
total 3.1 GB and 2 files
```

Or if you have a better way for this command I will appreciate, thanks

Comment: You might find the `du` command helpful,  with the `-s` and `-h` arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | sort -z | while IFS= read -r -d '' i ; do echo -n "$i: " ; echo ; list=$(find "$i" -type f  | sed -n 's/..*\.//p'| sort | uniq -c); ; echo "Total $(du -sh $i | cut -f -1| tr -d '\n') and $(x=0; for i in $list; do y=$(cut -f -1 <<< $i); x=$(($x+$y)); done; echo $x) files"; done
```

The only thing this does not do is find the sum of the size per filetype. To do this, instead of `echo $list`, you want to do something like this:

```
for x in $list; ext=$(cut -d' ' -f2 << $x); do du -sch ${i}/*.${ext} | tail -n1 | cut -f -1; echo $x; done
```

I was unable to get the cut command used to extract the extension from `$list` but I believe that's just a matter of fiddling with the loop and format of `$x`

Comment: Thanks Ted your solution is good for the totals in whole folder, I continue looking how to extract the total size and files by extensions